# Correctly save R script to keep encoding for Slovak characters when reopened? Windows 10

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, rstudio

I am looking for a correct way to treat Slovak characters in R studio.

---

I create a new R script, set local system to Slovak, and add my characters:

```
# Check Slovak characters

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Slovak")

chars <-c("ľ š č ť ž ý á í é ú ä ň ô")
```

Which prints out correct characters.

```
> chars
[1] "ľ š č ť ž ý á í é ú ä ň ô"
```

I save the R script with the encoding Windows-1252, as this one is used by Libre Office and Excel to correctly display Slovak characters.

[image]

I close the R script.

I reopen my R script in R studio, and some of my Slovak characters had been magically replaced by different characters!

[image]

Compared to my previous output!

```
> chars
    [1] "ľ š č ť ž ý á í é ú ä ň ô"
```

Please, can you advice me how to choose the correct encoding for Slovak characters, and save the R script in a way, that the characters will not change when I open the R script again?

I am using Windows 10 and R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) under RStudio.

Comment: Try `source(<path-to-script>, encoding = "CP-1252")`?

Comment: @mako212 I am not sure how to use your suggestion in my script? When I have created a new script and tried to load it, or to inserted it right in the console: `source("C:/Users/test 1/win1252.R", encoding = "CP-1252")`, I got Error:
`Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  unsupported conversion from 'CP-1252' to '' ` Do you know what can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my text editor, some of those characters cannot be represented in `Windows 1252` encoding. See below error from Sublime Text when I try to Save with encoding... a .R file with your provided character string:

[image]

I'd recommend you try saving with `UTF-8` encoding, that should hopefully fix the issue.

`Windows 1250` is also apparently valid, but I'd go with `UTF-8` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Thank you @mako212, this is probably the only way. It works for the new scripts but not for old ones, but it definitely clarifies at least some of my confusions. I will follow your advices.